# Check all $_POST vars and validate based on class

Tags: php, jquery, validation

For my Jquery, I use classes to define the type of validation used on that object. For example:

```
<input class="NUMBER_VALIDATE" type="text" maxlength="80" name="PRICE" id="PRICE" value="PRICE">
```

Jquery checks all the NUMBER_VALIDATE to make sure they are numbers and then displays error. I also want to do this server-side using PHP.

Therefore, this is what I need: PHP will loop through $_POST vars, then check each of elements that created the $_POST if it has NUMBER_VALIDATE in it. If it does and it is not a number, it will not add it to the database.

My NAME & ID are identical.

I need therefore something like this:

```
foreach($_POST)
{
GET THE NAME USED FOR THE POST VAR, (for example PRICE)
USE PRICE TO LOCATE THE ELEMENT, AND GET THE CLASS
IF THE CLASS IS NUMBER_VALIDATE, VALIDATE THE $_POST FOR NUMBERS
}
```

Comment: `$_POST` does not pass classes. You have to do this a different way, or do it through javascript (although people can disable javascript).

Comment: This would be a questionable way to validate, as it "trusts the client". Instead, the server should re-associate each GET/POST entry with the applicable validation and business rule logic.

Comment: Well, can I get the NAME from the $_POST? $_POST['PRICE'] ... get PRICE, and then PRICE is my ID for the element, so get the ELEMENT by id PRICE taken from the name.

Comment: @MaciekSemik Re-association is generally done with names, yes; however, it is the servers responsibility to look at the name and then determine the appropriate validation for it.

Comment: @user2864740, thats why I validate using Jquery, then I want to validate using PHP.

Comment: @MaciekSemik Validation is done in JavaScript *for a better user experience and immediate feedback* (the JS validations should *cover* the server validations), then validations are done on the server/PHP *to ensure business rules are not violated* - ever. There are approaches to try and integrate the two *different* validation situations, but keeping a clear model can go a long way.

Comment: I know. I separate my PHP and JQ validation. I'm just trying to find a more efficient way to process dozens of number inputs using PHP using NAME or CLASS or ID to pinpoint the exact process to undertake.

Comment: This i just a bad idea, sorry.  Your PHP has to encode this information separately, otherwise it will be insecure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a string to the beginning of the name, then strip that string when processing

```
<input class="NUMBER_VALIDATE" name="NUMBER-VALIDATE-PRICE" id="PRICE" value="100.00">

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(stripos($key, "NUMBER-VALIDATE-") > -1) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: But if Javascript is disabled, the string will never be appended.

Comment: He's hardcoding the classes into the HTML. Just hardcode them before the value. No javascript required; validated in PHP. Problem solved. :)

Comment: But then they will show up in the text-box before the price. The user can (*and most likely will*) remove the extra text before submitting it.

Comment: You're right. D'oh! back to the drawing board... :)

Comment: Can you do something like... IF NAME contains NUMBER_VALIDATE?

Comment: `if(stripos($key, "NUMBER_VALIDATE") > -1)`

Comment: Yeah, already did it. @David saw me getting ahead of myself and reeled me back in :)

Comment: @Tim By the way, your `substr` there is going to return everything after the `NUMBER_VALIDATE` if you are adding it to the beginning, so you should rewrite it `substr($key, 0, 16)`.

Comment: @David Yeah, you're right. I updated using your suggestion. looks good?

Comment: This looks awesome. This is exactly what I need. Will make things a lot more efficient.

Comment: @MaciekSemik Glad we could help.

Comment: This is not a great idea... There is nothing stopping a naughty user from changing the name to something slightly different, which will not be validated, ultimately resulting in some sort of security breach

Comment: To be honest, even if they change the name and want to waste their time doing that, the worst they can do is put a 'letters' in place of 'numbers.'

Comment: @Ryley, please explain to me how a user is going to change the name of a form element from within their browser.

Comment: Using Firebug for Firefox, Developer Tools for IE, or the Chrome Console, the user has access to changing any and all details of the form they are submitting.  Beyond that, a user can replicate any POST of a form from the command line using simple tools like wget.

Comment: @Ryley Then there's nothing stopping a naughty user from doing that to ANY form on the internet, right? If the OP does server-side validation and checks that the names match, then what's the problem? According to you **every single form on the internet is vulnerable**, so how does that make *this* form the one that stands out as a security problem? Especially if he's validating the `POST` data?

Comment: He's validating the POST data using validation information provided by the user.  That's 100% of the problem.  A good answer to this question should explain how the server side script can validate the form data without relying on user-provided validation data.  For example, have a PHP array that associates the name of the form input with the validation information and class.  Use that array to create the form and also to validate it on POST.

Comment: @Ryley I think you need to read the OP's question again, that's not what he's doing at all. He wants to validate based upon criteria HE entered; originally by CSS, now by the name of the form field. And a good answer is one that solves the OP's question - whether it's done the way you want or not - and doesn't go on and on solving problems he never said he had. How about having some faith that the OP knows how to loop through the values and validate them himself?

Comment: I disagree, sorry.  We should not give advice that encourages terrible security practice.  Not just for OP but for anyone reading afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` does not pass classes. In order to use classes, you will have to validate using Javascript:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){

    for(var i = 0; i < $(this).find(".NUMBER_VALIDATE").length; i++)
    {
        if(isNaN($($(this).find(".NUMBER_VALIDATE")[i]).val())
        {
            //test failed
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

---

Note that people can disable Javascript, however, so this code will not run in that case. I would recommend you find a different way to validate with PHP.

**The only things** that are passed to PHP by forms are the name and value. This may be one of the few times when you should hard-code the validation in, rather than relying on a dynamic variable to do so.

Comment: Forgive me for saying so, but I think this is one of those few times when you should hard-code the validation by name.

Comment: I agree with having the server take appropriate action based on a pre-defined mapping of the name (which is why I am opposed to using "flags" in names).

Comment: @user2864740 I removed the flags part from my answer; I agree with you it's not a very good practice, but I was just trying to come up with suggestions.